# Cloud Function deploy function to selected project

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I read the [Cloud Fucntions docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)  and successfully deployed and it's working great. In my Firebase I have two projects, debug and production and they have different package names.

I can't find out how to deploy the function to my production project only to the debug project. Where do I change the target for deploy since I am singed in using google into Firebase and the projects debug/production is there.

Answer (score 16):

You need to add the other project first. Open a terminal in your functions folder (not in the subfolder functions) and write `firebase use --add` after that you can select the project via `firebase use YourProjectName`

Comment: ok I will try, I actually changed this file .firebaserc but that did not fly

Comment: Confirming this solution worked for my use case. I have 2 Firebase projects for the same Android project. One is for testing, the other for production. I deployed the same index.js code to both Firebase projects with this solution. No issues.